# AWS Amplify is returning 403 error only when a "location" query param is specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have a site hosted with AWS Amplify, and every URL that has a `location` query parameter returns something like:

```
403 Forbidden

<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>THSG05EH8EYB1E7N</RequestId>
<HostId>n6Ycon+6kmnmIMiH47lLxNiXhXduG4QzJstmzNeEfBYy3AV19PisdKfXHN99LIAE2cZgvLJ1FBQ=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Suppose my site is: https://example.com

Access to:

```
https://example.com --> works
https://example.com?anyotherparam=anyvalue --> works
https://example.com/ --> works
https://example.com/anyurl --> works
https://example.com/anyurl?anyotherparam=anyvalue --> works
https://example.com/any/sub/url -> works
https://example.com/any/sub/url?anyotherparam=anyvalue -> works
https://example.com?location --> returns 403
https://example.com?location?anyvalue --> returns 403
https://example.com/anyurl?location --> returns 403
https://example.com/anyurl?location=anyvalue --> returns 403
https://example.com/any/sub/url?location --> returns 403
https://example.com/any/sub/url?location=anyvalue --> returns 403
```

Any idea what can cause this?

Edit: I don't know if related... but in Amplify redirects, I configured the AWSDoc recommended redirect for SPAs rule:

```
Address: </^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>
DestinationAddress: /index.html
RedirectType: 200
```

Comment: I just tried this out on my own deployed Amplify site and I found that it gives the exact behavior you described. I don't have any custom redirects configured either. This is a weird one. Might make sense to open this as an issue with AWS

Comment: Its already opened... but no response

Comment: I can confirm the behaviour. Our solution was to rename "location" query param to "place"

Comment: I used that too... But its a weird bug

Comment: FYI: Error was reported here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=337362&tstart=0. No responses yet.

Comment: Seeing the same thing... I assume it's a simple error, since there isn't a lot of follow up here, but if you have a resolution could you post it?

Comment: No, my solution was to rename "location" param to "place"...

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had my `buildSpec>artifacts>files` set to '*' and not '**/*' so any files not in the baseDirectory would result in a 403.

Updating `files` to '**/*' resolved the issue.

```
          artifacts:
            baseDirectory: dist/
            files:
              - '**/*'
```

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/1403#issuecomment-749915604

Comment: In my case, the files were OK, because if I open any of them without the "location" parameter it worked. It just fail if the "location" param was included.